# Latex - BibTeX throws 3 errors

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm quite new to LaTeX, so the problem might be simple, but I'm not sure about why....
I'm using LaTeX on Windows, (MiKTeX) and working with Texmaker.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
```

Then somewhere in the code I have `\cite{DUMMY:1}` and in the end of my document I have

```
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The file `bib.bib` does look like the following:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}
```

That's all. When I now use the fast compile option, everything runs fine, BUT there is nothing in the bibliography (in the pdf generated), nor I have a real cite (just saying [DUMMY:1])... Of course, this happens because I have to use bibtex to compile. But when I now try using bibtex, it throws the following errors:

`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: t2000.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file t2000.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file t2000.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file t2000.aux (There were 3 error messages)`

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Is there by the way maybe an even easier way to use cites in LaTeX?

Thanks

Comment: Recent versions of bib latex default to use Buber as the backend processor. Use the optional argument [backend=bibtex]. To force the use of bibtex.

Comment: You should use biber instead of bibtex.

Comment: Based on the error i received when running your MWE, I changed `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. I then deleted all the temporary files and ran `latex` and `bibtex` commands.  No errors were generated. Afterwards, running `pdflatex` commands give correct output. **delete** temporary files before you try this procedure since otherwise `bibtex` will complain about `wrongly formatted` `aux` files.

Comment: Did you compile you bibtex-file?

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer says, you shouldn't use `bibtex`. Use `biblatex` with the `biber` backend. This means you need to run the `biber` program instead of the `bibtex` program.

Comment: Better use Biber with `backend=biber` (this is just to mark the back-end explicitly, if you don't give the `backend` option it defaults to `backend=biber`) and configure your editor accordingly, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 4):

If you use `biblatex` and `bibtex` you have to add option `backend=bibtex` to `biblatex`.  And you should define a style you want to use to layout the resulting bibliography, for example `style=alphabetic`.

So with the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and TeX code in one compilable MWE; see main changes in tex code marked with `<========`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
  AUTHOR    = {John Doe},
  TITLE     = {The Book without Title},
  PUBLISHER = {Dummy Publisher},
  YEAR      = {2100},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex, % bibtex biber <=====================================
  style=alphabetic % <=================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <======================================

\begin{document}
Text \cite{DUMMY:1} Text
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

If you want to use `biber` and style `numeric`, then please have a look to the following MWE (please see, that I deleted all other of your packages which were not relevant to your bibliography problem!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
  AUTHOR    = {John Doe},
  TITLE     = {The Book without Title},
  PUBLISHER = {Dummy Publisher},
  YEAR      = {2100},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % bibtex biber  % <====================================
  style=numeric % <=====================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text \cite{DUMMY:1} Text
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now **copy the MWE above** (chnaging your code is the next step!) into a new directory, for example with name `mwe.tex`, open a terminal or console, change to this directory and run first `pdflatex mwe.tex`, then **important** `biber mwe`, then two times `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  This way you and I have the same code and can talk about error warnings, if you get some (I doubt you will).

You can always compile with `biber` (or change `biber` to `bibtex` to run BibTeX), independent from the editor you use.

If that three commands result in the wanted pdf, then you can look into the configuration of your editor to learn, how to use `biber` with it.

But please see: **if you change the backend for `biblatex`, you have to use the named program there!**

Then you will get the result:

[image]

If you want to add images into your TeX document, you need to call package `graphicx` (I deleted it in my MWE, because it had nothing to do with bibliography!), copy the image in the same directory and add command `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}` where you want to have the image printed.

But that would be better another question, only one question per question here please.

It could be you are using an outdated system?  Please add the command `\listfiles` in the line before `\documentclass`, compile and check your log file. At the end of it you will find a list of used packages and version numbers for my MWE.  Compare this list with mine (current MiKTeX 2.9):

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
csquotes.sty    2016/01/31 v5.1g context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2016/01/31 v5.1g csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
 numeric.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.def    
standard.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
  german.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ngerman.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 308326a.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: While the answer is technically correct I don't think that it is a good idea to tell new users to switch to the bibtex backend. I doubt that the OP used bibtex knowingly.

Comment: I doubt that the OP has enough knowledge to decide between bibtex and biber, and tags of new users often have a random element.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right, I didn't use `bibtex` "knowingly", I just found that in many online tutorials so I tried to use it. I will now try to implement a combination of the comments and this answer, come back to you if it's working fine

Comment: Somehow it's not working... I tried using `\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}` now, but still getting the same errors... When I try to delete the `.aux` file, bibtex can't find it anymore. Actually, when I try to compile the file with LaTeX chosen, it throws some errors as well (as I always used "Fast compile" until now.....The errors I'm getting there are all about files (`File xxx not found`). Maybe I include them wrong? Just writing `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image}`, while the images are all in the same folder as the tex file.

Comment: You need to use biber instead of bibtex. See e.g. http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1909/wie-verwende-ich-biber-in-meinem-editor. Images are a new problem and should go in a new questuin.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I now also followed the tip with using biber in Texmaker, the compiling also went fine now, but afterwards the "fast compile" option delivers lots of erros (that I didn't get before) (and still no cite in the text)

Comment: I'll ask about that issue in another question, as it doesn't seem to be a problem of biblatex anymore, but of the compiling itself...